# New cluster in Elasticsearch gets Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.tools.JavaVersionChecker

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have implemented a new cluster of `Elasticearch v7.12.0` with:

- 6 nodes
- 2 masters.

After the servers were installed I saw that all of the `Elasticsearch` services are **dead**.

When starting them I got:

`Error: Could not find or load main class org.Elasticsearch.tools.JavaVersionChecker.`

The java params are:

- `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`
- `java version "1.8.0_152"`

Can you please assist me with this?

Comment: fwiw you have no majority with 2 masters, so you risk losing your cluster

Comment: you'd need to share more of your Elasticsearch logs, and your entire elasticsearch.yml

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49225092/573153 might be a good starting point — it was for 6.x but the same error.